# Android screen orientation to sensor

Tags: android, orientation

I want to force the screen orientation to landscape on button click by setting

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

It works fine. Now I want the application to follow the sensor so that orientation is brought back to portrait when tilted back to portrait. I know this is possible by setting `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` but don't know where to set it. If the orientation is forced to landscape, orientation will remain in landscape no matter you tilt in any direction. Can anyone specify how to reset the orientation flag?

Answer (score 11):

Current YouTube app does what you are asking for.
I've dealt with same kind of problem in my application for video playback. 
If user forces orientation to landscape when he/she was in portrait, initialise **OrientationEventListener** which notifies you on device orientation from `SensorManager` which ranges from 0 to 360. 
Watch if device tilts to landscape orientation range which would be around `(orientation >= 60 && orientation <= 120) || (orientation >= 240 && orientation <= 300)` and save this state to a enum or a flag and then if device goes back to Portrait orientation range (`orientation <= 40 || orientation >= 320`), check the enum/flag and call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);` , reset the flag/enum and disable the sensor until user force orientation again.
Here is the demo code:

```
private enum SensorStateChangeActions {
        WATCH_FOR_LANDSCAPE_CHANGES, SWITCH_FROM_LANDSCAPE_TO_STANDARD, WATCH_FOR_POTRAIT_CHANGES, SWITCH_FROM_POTRAIT_TO_STANDARD;
}

private SensorStateChangeActions mSensorStateChanges;

public void goFullScreen() {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        mSensorStateChanges = SensorStateChangeActions.WATCH_FOR_LANDSCAPE_CHANGES;
        if (null == sensorEvent)
            initialiseSensor(true);
        else
            sensorEvent.enable();
}

public void shrinkToPotraitMode() {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mSensorStateChanges = SensorStateChangeActions.WATCH_FOR_POTRAIT_CHANGES;
        if (null == sensorEvent)
            initialiseSensor(true);
        else
            sensorEvent.enable();
}
/**
 * Initialises system sensor to detect device orientation for player changes.
 * Don't enable sensor until playback starts on player
 *
 * @param enable if set, sensor will be enabled.
 */
private void initialiseSensor(boolean enable) {
    sensorEvent = new OrientationEventListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            /*
             * This logic is useful when user explicitly changes orientation using player controls, in which case orientation changes gives no callbacks.
             * we use sensor angle to anticipate orientation and make changes accordingly.
             */
            if (null != mSensorStateChanges
                    && mSensorStateChanges == SensorStateChangeActions.WATCH_FOR_LANDSCAPE_CHANGES
                    && ((orientation >= 60 && orientation <= 120) || (orientation >= 240 && orientation <= 300))) {
                mSensorStateChanges = SensorStateChangeActions.SWITCH_FROM_LANDSCAPE_TO_STANDARD;
            } else if (null != mSensorStateChanges
                    && mSensorStateChanges == SensorStateChangeActions.SWITCH_FROM_LANDSCAPE_TO_STANDARD
                    && (orientation <= 40 || orientation >= 320)) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                mSensorStateChanges = null;
                sensorEvent.disable();
            } else if (null != mSensorStateChanges
                    && mSensorStateChanges == SensorStateChangeActions.WATCH_FOR_POTRAIT_CHANGES
                    && ((orientation >= 300 && orientation <= 359) || (orientation >= 0 && orientation <= 45))) {
                mSensorStateChanges = SensorStateChangeActions.SWITCH_FROM_POTRAIT_TO_STANDARD;
            } else if (null != mSensorStateChanges
                    && mSensorStateChanges == SensorStateChangeActions.SWITCH_FROM_POTRAIT_TO_STANDARD
                    && ((orientation <= 300 && orientation >= 240) || (orientation <= 130 && orientation >= 60))) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                mSensorStateChanges = null;
                sensorEvent.disable();
            }
        }
    };
    if (enable)
        sensorEvent.enable();
}
```

This worked similar to YouTube functionality, hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for: a way to emulate what the YouTube app was doing! Thanks :)

Comment: @CodeFury How to use this and what is sensorEvent?

Comment: This is really nice answer

Comment: can you show how to use this code in a project or a demo project?

Comment: this is not working when go to landscap from portrait .

Answer (score 4):

I think here you should use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you want the sensor to detect rotation again.

Personally in an app I'm developping I have one specific activity where I need to be in portrait mode, so I use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in the `onResume()` of this activity and `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` in `onPause()` and it works just fine, when I enter the activity it sets to portrait if it's not and doesn't allow to change and on exitting the sensor works again...

Where are you trying to enable and disable the sensor?

Comment: My application is in portrait mode by default. User can switch to landscape mode either by clicking a button or by tilting the device. But on landscape mode, there is no way to bring the activity back to portrait mode. If another button has to be provided to force the orientation to portrait, then this will be the last option. I wanted to know is it possible to set to sensor mode after forcing to landscape. I tried your option t set to sensor mode on pause, but it will revert back to portrait mode when i want to force to landscape mode when device is in portrait mode.